# PHP/ Ajax/ jQuery - Equivalent for my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code and would like to use jquery to make it simpler:

var auctionBidAjax;

```
function auctionBid(auction_id) {
  auctionBidAjax=GetXmlHttpObject();
  if (auctionBidAjax==null) {
    alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    return;
  }
  var url="/cms/ajax/auctionBid.php?auction_id="+auction_id;
  auctionBidAjax.onreadystatechange=function() { auctionBidReady(auction_id); };
  auctionBidAjax.open("GET",url,true);
  auctionBidAjax.send(null);
}
```

And...

```
function auctionBidReady(auction_id) {
  if (auctionBidAjax.readyState==4) {
    if (auctionBidAjax.responseText == "Bid Placed") {
      document.getElementById('auctionBid' + auction_id).innerHTML=
        "<a href=\"javascript:auctionBid("+auction_id+");\">Place Bid</a>";
      userBids();
    } else if (auctionBidAjax.responseText == "Not Logged In") {
      popupCentre('popupLogin');
      popupLoad('popupLogin');
    } else if (auctionBidAjax.responseText == "No Bids"){
      popupCentre('popupNoBids');
      popupLoad('popupNoBids');
    }
  }
}
```

My PHP script adds a bid etc and echos the responseText.

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged this question as jquery so you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options):

```
function auctionBid(auction_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/cms/ajax/auctionBid.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      auction_id: auction_id
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // act appropriately
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
      // do whatever
    }
  });
}
```

If you didn't need an error handler you could use the simpler form of [`$.get()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) instead:

```
function auctionBid(auction_id) {
  var url = "/cms/ajax/auctionBid.php";
  $.get(url, { auction_id: auction_id }, function(data, textStatus) {
    // do whatever
  });
}
```

I actually prefer not to use error handlers. It's a little uglier than it needs to be. Use that for actual errors. Things like "not logged in" could be handled by the success handler. Just pass back a JSON object that contains the required information to tell the user what happened.

For this you could use the [`$.getJSON()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) shorthand version.

```
function auctionBid(auction_id) {
  var url = "/cms/ajax/auctionBid.php";
  $.getJSON(url, { auction_id: auction_id }, function(data) {
    if (data.notLoggedIn) {
      alert("Not logged in");
    }
    ...
  });
}
```

To return some information as JSON from PHP use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and set the MIME type appropriately:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
  'highBid' => get_new_high_bid(),
  'loggedIn' => $_SESSION['loggedIn'],
));
exit;
?>
```

I'm making assumptions about your login system so the above is a gross simplification.

Return that to a `$.getJSON()` callback and you should be able to do:

```
alert(data.highBid);
alert(data.loggedIn);
```

Comment: Hi Cletus,

Brilliant that looks perfect, how do I use what used to be response.Text? That's the only thing I'm now confused about!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of how to utilise what is returned? Sorry for being dumb =/

Comment: wrap alert(data) in the callback, you can then manipulate the returned html and inject/overwrite/add to do partial update.

Comment: OK that sounds interesting, where and how in PHP would I set notLoggedIn? Sorry!

Comment: Oh I see, so data is the equivelent of responseText!

Comment: How do i set "data" in the PHP script, just return variables?

Comment: I am not entire sure why .notLoggedIn method appears (and it seems invalid to me). Remember the data here is whatever you return from your server (php) side script, you only have the power the manipulate whatever returns.

Comment: OK Jay Zeng cool, can i return multiple pieces of data? Or is what I echo the data? I.E echo $var, $var will become data?

Comment: Cletus that's brilliant, thanks so much! Is it ok to use json for one bit of data? Or is it better to use the others you gave me?

Thanks again!!!!! <3

Comment: I tend to use either HTML (to insert a fragment directly into the document) or JSON to pass information. You can use XML and I think plain text too. Using JSON for 1-2 bits of data is fine.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery.get is what you need
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get